# publish port when running 'docker exec'

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Inside a docker conrainer, on a **Windows machine** I have to run some Laravel tests, in which a command is run, producing the following Exception trace:

Exception trace:

**Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused**

> 1
> Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor::execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand))
> /var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:135
>
> 2
> Facebook\WebDriver\Remote**RemoteWebDriver::create("http://localhost:8000",
> Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities))**
> /var/www/html/tests/DuskTestCase.php:44

To kick off the docker container, the following command is run

```
docker exec -it crawler-php bash
```

and then a phpunit test is run inside the container, producing the exception with **RemoteWebDriver**

I suspect the Exception is caused by port 8000 not being Exposed or Published properly, but I'm new to docker and am unsure how to ammend the issue. (I'm also not entirely sure if it's publishing or exposing of port 8000 that I have to do)

I'm aware that one can run the command `docker run -p 8000:8000...` to run a container with port 8000 published and mapped to my local machines port 8000, but I am unsure of how to have a similar container port mapping when `docker exec` is being used instead of `docker run`

Comment: So - did you try the `docker run` command you've given? What happened? Docker exec is used to shell into a container which is already running. I notice you say that `exec` is used *"kick off"* the container. This is not the case - you must already have a container running, and it's in the `run` command that you need to map the port. `docker ps` will show what containers you have running, and `docker inspect <container name>` will show the details (ports etc) of the running container

Comment: Yes, I tried the following command: `docker run -p 8000:8000 -it crawler-php bash`.

The result was this:...........................................
*Unable to find image 'crawler-php:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for crawler-php, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.*...............................................................................

The abover 'docker run' cmd is identical to the exec command used, with exec & run swapped.

Comment: Why are you making the main container command `bash`?  It should usually actually run the program you want to run in the container.

Comment: thanks. That was a dumb addition to the **run** command

Answer (score 0):

for Windows,
on the host machine, you can use `netsh` an example,

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=(local address) listenport=(local port) connectaddress=(destination address) connectport=(destination port)`

For Linux,
On the host machine, to create a rule on iptables,

`iptables -t nat -D DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp --dport 3306-j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3306`

When a packet's destination is to port `3306` on the host, forward the packet to the container with ip `172.17.0.2`, and the port `3306`.
the -i parameter is the docker interface.

From what i could find in terms of simplicity, without creating a new container.

Comment: thanks, I'm on a windows machine, so I guess I'll have to figure out a slightly different method. (no iptables cmd on windows :(   )